# Getting 500 ERROR when doing an AJAX request in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel. I'm trying to make an AJAX request in my laravel app but I'm getting a 500 (Internal Server Error). 
So, here is my request in the .blade file:

```
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $('#getRequest').on('click', function () {
            $.get('getMessages', function (data) {
               $('#target').append(data);
            });
       });
     });
   </script>
```

I added the .ajaxSetup to make sure tokens are not the reason for this problem. So I typed in this .blade file also the following tag:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Here is my route.php file:

```
Route::get('getMessages', 'PagesController@getMessages');
```

And here is my controller with the method in cause:

```
public function getMessages()
{
    return "OK";
}
```

The problem is tricky to me, because I know that I can create a anonimous function in my route.php file for this URI and it's gonna be the same thing. Or not. I don't know because if I actually do this

```
Route::get('getMessages', function ()
{
    return "OK";
});
```

instead of pointing to a method of a controller, it works! But I need it to work in a controller.

My controller is functioning properly when it comes to other methods and the name of the method is spelled correctly everywhere.

I'm working with XAMPP on Windows. I set XAMPP to work only with the current Laravel app, so when I type in "localhost" in my browser, it gets me to my app page and all of database data fetching work properly.

Comment: I realized that I misspelled the controller name. But there's still a problem. When I check if it's a ajax request I get the same error. And it works if I run this check directly from the routes.php file.


`if (Request::ajax()) {       return 'ho';    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably set your `ENV` to local so you can debug your code.

Maybe a faster solution for you would be for you to check the `storage/logs/laravel.log` and see the last stack trace so you can determine exactly where the error is coming from.